# Dollars and cents counter

Tags: java, currency

So I got an assignment to write a counter that adds a given amount of dollars and cents together. We were given a test class that is being used to test functionality.

We were given the following hints:

```
public int dollars () //The dollar count. 
ensure: this.dollars () >= 0

public int cents () //The cents count. 
ensure: 0 <= this.cents() && this.cents() <= 99
```

And:

```
public void add (int dollars, int cents) //Add the specified dollars and cents to this Counter. 
public void reset () //Reset this Counter to 0. 
ensure: this .dollars() == 0 && this.cents() == 0
```

This is my current code:

```
public class Counter {

    private float count;

    public Counter() {
        count = 0;
    }

    public int dollars() {
        if (this.dollars() >= 0) {
            count = count + Float.parseFloat(this.dollars() + "." + 0);
        } return 0;
    }

    public int cents() {
        if (0 <= this.cents() && this.cents() <= 99) {
            count = count + Float.parseFloat(+0 + "." + this.cents());
        } else if (100 <= this.cents()) {
            count = count + Float.parseFloat(+1 + "." + (this.cents() - 100));
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void add(int dollars, int cents) {
        dollars = this.dollars();
        cents = this.cents();
    }

    public void reset() {
        count = 0;  
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

I realize I am making mistakes here (supposedly at the float and trying to calculate the dollar and cents part of the float). But I can not pinpoint exactly where it fails.

Comment: Your `main()` method is empty, for starters.

Comment: I am not sure how that affects the functionality since testing the class is done from another class.

Comment: Then why do you have it? And what's the actual problem?

Comment: Too many problems: (1) Calling `dollars()` inside `dollars()` leading to infinite recursion (same for `cents`). (2) Adding values to `count` nearly everywhere except where it should be done. And probably more.

Comment: @user3757962 Tip: Don't use `float` for currency values. In this case you should change the field `count` to an int and count the number of cents (convert the dollars to cents and convert them back when you need to)

Comment: Too many problems, it's difficult to know where to start, but: 1) Method `add` is supposed to update the field(s) of your class. It doesn't. 2) Do not use `float`. Suggest you use 2 `int` fields instead, one for `dollars` value and one for `cents` value. 3) The "ensure" range conditions should be done on the `add` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public final class Counter {

    private int cents;

    public int dollars() {
        return cents / 100;
    }

    public int cents() {
        return cents;    // if you want to retrun all centes
        // return cents % 100;    // if you want to return cents less than dollar
    }

    public void add(int dollars, int cents) {
        this.cents = dollars * 100 + cents;
    }

    public void reset() {
        cents = 0;
    }
}
```

One very important rule for financial programming: **NEVER USE FLOAT AS COUNTER MONEY**. You definetly have problem with it soon or even very soon. See my example, actuall your counter could be implemented very easy just holding amount of cents as int (as I can see, you do not have part of cents).

**P.S. One trick for a future**

Imagine you need a floating point values and support all standard mathematical operations on them, like `+,-,/,*`. E.g. dollar and integer amount of cents (like in your example) and you cannot (or do not want) to use floating operations. What should you do?

Just reserver two lowes digis in integer valus as fractional part. So let's take an example for price $12:

```
int price = 1200;    // 00 is reserverd for centes, , price is $12
price += 600;        // add $6, price is $18
price += 44;         // add $0.44, price is $18.55

int dollars = price / 100;   // retrieve total dollars - $18     
int cents = cents % 100;     // retrieve cents less than dollars - 44
```

Comment: “rule for financial programming:” this isn’t about financial programming, it’s a simple homework for beginners so while this is a good solution it’s misses the mark because it’s to advanced for someone than doesn’t know the difference between methods and members

Comment: Anyway. countic money should not be done with float!

Comment: I am certainly not disagreeing with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Counter {

    private int dollars = 0;
    private int cents = 0;

    public Counter(int dollars, int cents) {
        this.dollars = dollars;
        this.cents = cents;
    }

    Counter reset() {
        return new Counter(0, 0);
    }

    Counter add(int dollars, int cents) {
        if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        int dollarsToAdd = this.dollars + dollars;
        int centsToAdd = this.cents + cents;

        if (centsToAdd > 99) {
            dollarsToAdd += centsToAdd / 100;
            centsToAdd = centsToAdd % 100;
        }
        return new Counter(dollarsToAdd, centsToAdd);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.dollars + "." + this.cents);
    }

}
```

1) Using two counters instead of one. It makes calculations easy and avoids problems with floating points. (Check this out `System.out.println(1.03 - .42);` )

2) Validating inputs. Can't add negative amounts.

3) cents/100 will return number of full dollars. Since dividing int by int removes decimal points.

4) cents%100 will return remainder - cents left after converting to full dollars.

5) let's make it immutable. It will avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: Good solution but too advanced, skip the immutable/concurrency stuff and no throwing exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful answers here. I also realized I did not understand the assignment correctly (thinking I would need a total amount of money instead of two separate counters for dollars and cents) and thus I made this harder than it needed to be.

My solution (which is verified to work by using the test class provided) is as follows:

```
public final class Counter {

    private int dollars;
    private int cents;

    public int dollars() {

        return dollars;
    }

    public int cents() {
        return cents;
    }

    public void add(int dollars, int cents) {
        if (dollars >= 0) {
            if (0 <= cents && cents <= 99) {
                this.dollars += dollars;
                this.cents += cents;
            }
            if (this.cents > 100 | cents > 100) {
                this.dollars += this.cents / 100;
                this.cents = this.cents % 100;
            }
            if (this.cents == 100 | cents == 100) {
                this.dollars++;
                this.cents = this.cents - 100;
            }

        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        dollars = 0;
        cents = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout my answer. And think about how your code will work in case of adding more then 100 cents? E.g. add ( 1, 444 );

Comment: I see what you're saying. 444 cents would just add 1 dollar and subtract 100 cents from the 444 cents. I oversimplified this a little and will fix it. Thanks!